# Parametro (props) de componente padre se pasa undefined al componente hijo - Vue Js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, axios, component

Buen día Comunidad!

Estoy intentando pasar un objeto json (que me devuelve una petición Get) cómo parámetro de un componente padre a un componente hijo pero en el componente hijo me llega como 'undefined'.
Pienso que es porque la respuesta Get tarda más, por lo cual el parametro se pasa "vacio".

En el componente padre hago la llamada get con el método getSchema, hasta este punto si recibo correctamente response.data el cual asigno a Schema. En el template HTML construyo el componente hijo denominado DataTable y le paso como parametro el objeto Schema.table, el cual contiene los datos de la tabla.

```
mounted(){
        this.getSchema(this.Source);
    },
    methods: {
        async getSchema(){
            let response = await DataAccess.getAll(this.Source);
            this.Schema = response.data;
        }
    }

<DataTable v-else-if="MainComponent=='DataTable'" :Table="Schema.table"></DataTable>
```

Sin embargo al intentar recibirlo en el componente hijo, en el método mounted mando a escribir en consola ese parametro y viene como 'undifined'.

Pienso que el parametro se paso antes de que el objeto se llenara de la respuesta de la petición get.

```
props: {
        Table: {
            type: Object,
            description: "Table Schema"
        }
    },
    mounted(){
      console.log(this.Table);
    }
```

Comment: ¿this.Source tiene algún valor? ¿que pasa si su petición no se completa? quizas eso cause que Schema.table sea indefinido, puedes comprobar con un console.log que se esté completando la petición

Comment: Si, Source es el recurso que consume en el backend, o sea el endpoint. DataAccess.getAll es un método que tengo en unas clases externas de javascript que abstraen las consultas a la base de datos, Considero que no influye ya que si mando en consola la respuesta del metodo getAll si me obtiene el objeto json que espero.

Comment: El problema sucede al intentar pasar el objeto que obtuve de la base de datos al componente hijo. Pienso que cuando lo paso en el template html al componente hijo aún no tiene la respuesta del backend.

Comment: Exactamente por lo tanto tu componente hijo obligatoriamente debe manejar el caso de que el parametro Table sea undefined ya que la consulta no sea completado. puedes usar comprobaciones, valor por defecto (ej: objeto vacio) o Optional Chaining que es de EcmaScript 2020

Comment: Tambien puede ser factible renderizar el componente solo cuando la petición esté completa, con un v-if

Comment: Gracias por tus respuestas. No puedo dejar que el hijo maneje el caso porque el valor siempre va a llegar 'undefined', dicho de otra forma la renderización siempre va a ser más rápida por lo cual el parámetro siempre va a llegar vacio antes de que la petición en el padre concluya.

Comment: Considero más factible lo de renderizar el componente hijo hasta que la petición se haya completado. Sin embargo tengo que hacer la evaluación por cada componente que vaya a renderizar. ¿En VUE no hay alguna forma de indicar que debe renderizar hasta que termine la petición?

Comment: ¿Haz considerado usar v-if y v-else? Lo que comunmente hago es que tengo una animación de carga con un background y al terminar represento mis componentes que requieren de los datos que solicito